# PapaParseService' is not exported by node_modules/ngx-papaparse/dist/index.js

Tags: angular, papaparse

I'm using Angular 4 and want to use ngx-papaparse to parse some csv

I ran

```
yarn add -D ngx-papaparse@1.2.5
```

imported it in my app.module

```
import { PapaParseModule } from "ngx-papaparse";
  imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  PapaParseModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
  ],
```

and wrote the following code in my parser

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    import { PapaParseService } from "ngx-papaparse";

    @Injectable()

    export class ParserService {
      constructor(private papa: PapaParseService) {
        //
      }

      public getData(data) {
        const options = {
          complete: (results, file) => {
            console.log("Parsed: ", results, file);
          },
          // Add your options here
        };

        this.papa.parse(data, options);
      }
    }
```

But I keep getting this issue at compilation

```
[!] Error: 'PapaParseService' is not exported by node_modules/ngx-papaparse/dist/index.js
```

The weird thing is that my Stackblitz app accepts ngx-papaparse@3.0.2 and doesn't run in this issue, whereas trying to install 3.0.2 gives me this:

```
Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/node_modules/ngx-papaparse/ngx-papaparse.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3
```

Answer (score 3):

in your `parser-service.ts` file import as

> import { Papa} from "ngx-papaparse";

and then in constructor

```
constructor(private papa: Papa) {}
```

rest of the code is fine and after these changes it will work perfectly.

Comment: i get '/node_modules/ngx-papaparse/dist has no exported member "Papa"' when i do that :(

Comment: @Ben here is a link of working example by using your code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1tqdax

Comment: but only difference is you install this package using `yarn` while i installed it using `npm`

Comment: i think this works because you are using 3.0.2. It seems to me that on the 1.2.5 that i need to use on my Angular 2, it's actually 

import { PapaParseService } from "ngx-papaparse";

that i need to do in my service. However I still get the following error when compiling:
Error: 'PapaParseService' is not exported by node_modules/ngx-papaparse/dist/index.js

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and I managed to solve it.

Angular version and ngx-papaparse versions must be aligned.
To find the correct version of ngx-papaparse to use depending on your Angular's version, refer to this url: https://alberthaff.dk/projects/ngx-papaparse/docs/v4/introduction